# Franjas negras en el recorte con opencv

Tags: python, opencv

miren el caso es que tengo un problema. Estoy realizando un comparador de imágenes y que si la imagen es correcta la recorte. El problema es que en el recorte me aparecen unas franjas negras y quiero que sea preciso. Tengo el siguiente código:

```
#Detect Item
detect = {}

gray1 = cv2.cvtColor(jpguser, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
gray2 = cv2.cvtColor(raworiginalflip, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

## (2) Create SIFT object

minHessian = 400
sift = cv2.xfeatures2d_SURF.create(hessianThreshold=minHessian)

## (3) Create flann matcher
matcher = cv2.FlannBasedMatcher(dict(algorithm = 1, trees = 2), {})

## (4) Detect keypoints and compute keypointer descriptors
kpts1, descs1 = sift.detectAndCompute(gray1,None)
kpts2, descs2 = sift.detectAndCompute(gray2,None)

## (5) knnMatch to get Top2
matches = matcher.knnMatch(descs1, descs2, 2)
# Sort by their distance.
matches = sorted(matches, key = lambda x:x[0].distance)

## (6) Ratio test, to get good matches.
ratio_thresh = RATIO
good = []
for m,n in matches:
    if m.distance < ratio_thresh * n.distance:
        good.append(m)


detect['kpts1'] = kpts1
detect['kpts2'] = kpts2
detect['good'] = good
detect['raworiginal'] = raworiginalflip
detect['flipmode'] = flipmode

if len(detect['good']) >= MIN_MATCH_COUNT:
    return detect
else:
    if flipmode > VERTICAL_HORIZONTAL:
        return detect_matches(jpguser,raworiginal,flipmode-1)

return detect
```

El resultado es el siguiente[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si observais la imagen tiene dos pequeñas franjas negras en la esquina izquierda y la esquina derecha.¿Como podría arreglar esto?

Comment: ¿Puedes poner un enlace a la imagen original, antes de recortarla? Parece que las franjas ya formaban parte de esa imagen, en la que los bordes no serían perfectamente horizontales.

Comment: Si, aquí te dejo sobre la imagen que se extrae https://drive.google.com/file/d/1yUZ7KELhE6MoIllt-FAfgkOtFFP_QkdX/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Pues en esa imagen no se observan esas bandas. No veo claro en tu código dónde se produce el recorte y si antes de eso la imagen fue procesada de algún modo (algún filtro). Si es así, será ese paso el que introduce las bandas.

Comment: Este es el código completo en sí por si podéis ver el fallo o porque puede dar esas franjas https://paste.ofcode.org/Gxa8ekFvx8fmMKxcjFtsyw

Comment: Para poder ejecutar tu código necesito también la parte en que carga las imágenes `jpeguser` y `raworiginal` (así como estas imágenes). Y no sé si algo más.

Comment: Este es el código de prueba que estoy usando https://paste.ofcode.org/pGRp5H4rCkZECnutvHWFbq para ejecutarlo simplemente crea un bat en el que el parámetro -r vaya con el tiff que he pasado, el -u vaya con la siguiente imagen: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Q5OyEOvs3aJ10aOC3oEZaN9g3TLYpI7e/view?usp=sharing y el parámetro -o seria el directorio + nombre del archivo y extension. Mire en internet cómo hacerlo y empecé a formar el mío propio para aprender, pero no entiendo porque no es preciso y saca esas lineas negras. Lo curioso es que si logro quitarselas a esta imagen las saca en otras

Comment: No he podido replicar tu código. Al ejecutarlo acabo con un error que viene a decir que me falta un componente de la biblioteca porque es patentado y que tengo que recompilar OpenCV con la opción `OPENCV_ENABLE_NONFREE`. Como consecuencia no me genera ninguna imagen. No obstante me resulta sospechosa la linea `found = cv2.warpPerspective(raworiginal,perspectiveM,(w,h))`. Sospecho que causa un ligero giro (por un error de redondeo) de donde salen las bandas negras. Pero no sabría cómo cambiarlo para que no lo haga.

Comment: Da ese error porque para usar el algoritmo que estoy usando el surf hay que compilarlo manualmente y asi poder usar SURF y SIFT. Crees que sale de ahí el error? la verdad es que esa parte la encontré indagando por internet y no sabría ni como tocarla